# Installing - microsoft visual c++ 2003 redistributable package - Getting Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2003

When I'm trying to install "microsoft visual c++ 2003 redistributable package" getting an error "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing,....." error message.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are installing a service pack instead of the full thing?

I can't find any reference to c++ runtime 2003 either. Perhaps you mean 2005, or 2008?